# Unable to create new project in android

Tags: android

I've just update ADT and Android SDK to   `22.6.1`
 
 Thereafter come across one weird problem.
During creating new project in android there is drop down menu for selecting Minimum required SDK in first screen below Application name, Project name and Package name. But i am unable to open dropdown menu. So i skip that option and in the final screen it shows error

```
  "Navigation Type "None" requires a minimum SDK version of at least 1, and the current min version is 0".
```

Any one have faced this issue before?

Comment: That's weird...you cant select the drop down ???

Comment: http://tinypic.com/r/2a7u24g/8 have a look at this

Comment: Remove this update or Download a fresh copy of adt bundle.